# Connecting to screen

Tags: linux

How do I attach a screen? I can see a screen is running in the following output, but can not connect to it.

```
[root@vishnuvm6 ~]# screen -ls
There is a screen on:
        15941.pts-18.vishnuvm6  (Detached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-root.

[root@vishnuvm6 ~]# screen -x vishnuvm6
There is no screen to be attached matching vishnuvm6.
```

Comment: From `man screen`: "-x   Attach  to  a  ***not  detached*** screen session."

Comment: @Dennis: That just means existing clients, if any, won't get detached.

Comment: @grawity: Well, you're right, but that wording is very poor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since it's the only screen running *and* it is detached, you can simply:

```
screen -r
```

---

If it was attached, you could:

```
screen -d -r
```

to detach it first (I prefer `screen -Dr` though: "detach and logout first")

or:

```
screen -x
```

which will leave all other attached displays intact. A nice trick if you want to tutor on a terminal (for example).

---

You need to name the screen only if there are other *detached* screens.

Answer (score 3):

screen -d -r 15941.pts-18.vishnuvm6

Answer (score 3):

I use `screen -xRR` quite always.

- If no screen it starts one
- If a screen exists, attach to it